# Проблема отображения изображения в игре на Python

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Пишу игру на Python. Писать на данном языке программирования начал относительно недавно, поэтому не особо разбираюсь во всех мелочах. Просьба особо не критиковать. Проверил код пару раз. Ошибок в коде не выявил. При запуске кода открывает окно с черным экраном.[image: Игрок]

[image: Потенциальный враг - крокодил]
[image: Монета]

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img='player.png'):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

        self.couns = None
        self.collected_coins = 0

        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.alive = True

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.Spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.botttom

        coins_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.coins, False)
        for coin in coins_hit_list:
            self.collected_coins += 1
            coin.kill()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.enemies, False):
            self.alive = False


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


class Coin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img='coin.png'):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img='crocodile1.png'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.start = x
        self.stop = x + random.randint(180, 240)
        self.direction = 1

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x >= self.stop:
            self.rect.x = self.stop
            self.direction = -1
        if self.rect.x <= self.start:
            self.rect.x = self.startself.direction = 1
        self.rect.x += self.direction * 2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption('Ainel')

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

wall_coords = [
    [0, 0, 10, 600],
    [790, 0, 10, 600],
    [10, 0, 790, 10],
    [0, 200, 100, 10],
    [0, 590, 600, 10],
    [450, 400, 10, 200],
    [550, 450, 250, 10]
]
for coord in wall_coords:
    wall = Wall(coord[0], coord[1], coord[2], coord[3])
    wall_list.add(wall)
    all_sprite_list.add(wall)

coins_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
coins_coord = [[100, 140], [236, 50], [400, 234]]

for coord in coins_coord:
    coin = Coin(coord[0], coord[1])
    coins_list.add(coin)
    all_sprite_list.add(coin)

enemies_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies_coord = [[10, 500], [400, 50]]
for coord in enemies_coord:
    enemy = Enemy(coord[0], coord[1])
    enemies_list.add(enemy)
    all_sprite_list.add(enemy)

player = Player(50, 50)
player.walls = wall_list
all_sprite_list.add(player)

player.coins = coins_list
player.enemies = enemies_list


font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 24, True)
text = font.render('GAME OVER', True, WHITE)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.change_x = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.change_x = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.change_y = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.change_y = 3

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.change_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.change_x
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.change_y = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.change_y = 0


screen.fill(RED)
```

[Папки](http://127.0.0.1:5500/)

[Код](http://127.0.0.1:5500/%23pygame%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE.py)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В данный момент у меня запускается только окно с черным экраном. Мне нужно, чтобы у меня отрисовывалась сама игра вместе со всеми ее компонентами.

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]). А ваша ссылка на код содержит ссылку на ваш локальный, доступный только вам, приложите игру кодом

Comment: Добавил код игры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я смог разобраться с проблемой и сделать небольшую игру поэтому уже рабочий код вместе с игрой оставляю ниже

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
RLEACCEL,
)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 800


class Vstaf(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Vstaf, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("iy.jpg").convert()

    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 1.1, HEIGHT / 6.2)


    class Vstao(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Vstao, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("hy.jpg").convert()

    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 1.15, HEIGHT / 1.4)


    class Vstat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Vstat, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("by.jpg").convert()

    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 10.9)


    class Vstae(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Vstae, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("ly.jpg").convert()

    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 2.3)


class Vstav(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Vstav, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("ky.jpg").convert()

    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 10, HEIGHT / 1.4)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 50)
    super(Player, self).__init__()
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
    self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 40, HEIGHT / 33)

    def move(self, dx, dy):

    # Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
    if dx != 0:
        self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
    if dy != 0:
        self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):

    # Move the rect
    self.rect.x += dx
    self.rect.y += dy

    # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
    for wall in walls:
        if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
            if dx > 0:  # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            if dx < 0:  # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            if dy > 0:  # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            if dy < 0:  # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom


# Nice class to hold a wall rect
    class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
    walls.append(self)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

# Initialise pygame


    pygame.init()

# Set up the display
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))

    pygame.display.set_caption("Ainel")
    vstaf = Vstaf()
    vstao = Vstao()
    vstat = Vstat()
    vstae = Vstae()
    vstav = Vstav()
    player = Player()  # Create the player

    walls = []  # List to hold the walls

# Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
    level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W             W       W           WWWW              W         W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW  W    WWWW    WWWW          WWWWWWW    W         W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW  W    W          WWWWWWWWWWWW    W     W         W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW          WWWWW   W     W     W          W        W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWWWWWW              W   W           WWWWW   W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW  W       WWWW      W W   WW  W  W    WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWW   WWWWW   W    W    W W   WW     W    WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W W  WWWWWW           W    W    WWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W    WWWWWW   WWWWW   W    W          WW    WW W  WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W W  WWWWWW   W       W    WWWWWWWWW      WW     W            W",
"W             WWWWW             WW    WW                     WW",
"W W  WWWWWWWWWWW  WWWWWW        WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW         WW   W",
"W W                W            WW   W   W   WW    W     WW   W",
"WWWWWWW    WWWWW   W       WWWWWWWWW    W      W   WWWW       W",
"W          W   WWWWW   W  WW       W     W                    W",
"W   WWWWWWWW           W  WW  W  W W  W     WWWWWWWWWWWWWW    W",
"W              WWWW    W      W  W       W            W       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW W WWW  WWWWWWWWWWWW        W            W        W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW             WW        W      WW    W      W   W  W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW W WWW           WW W     W       WW    W   W  W  W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW   WWWWWW  WWWWWWW      WWW        WW          WW W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW W WWW     W        W    WWWWWWWWWWWW WWW   W  W  W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW   WWW  WWWW        W       WW     WWWWWWWWWW     W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWW   WWW     WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW     W               W",
"W            WWWWWWWW    W        W  WW  WWW      WWWW    WW  W",
"W    WWWWWWWWWWWWW      W    WW    WWW         WWW      WWWW  W",
"WWWW   WW       W      WWWWWW         WW   WW                 W",
"W     WWWWWWW   W      WWWWWWWWWW  W       W       W      WWWWW",
"WWW     WW    WWW  W         W       W WWW      WWWWW     W   W",
"W                       W    W      W     W W       W         W",
"WWWWWWW   WWWWWW        W           W         W      W W      W",
"W              W  WWWW             WWWW WW   W   WWW          W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW     WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW                         W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  WWWW      E        WWWW     WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW     W      WW        W       WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W        WWWWWW             WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
    for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
        Wall((x, y))
    if col == "E":
        end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
    x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

    running = True
    while running:

    for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False

# Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    player.move(-1, 0)
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    player.move(1, 0)
if key[pygame.K_UP]:
    player.move(0, -1)
if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    player.move(0, 1)

# Just added this to make it slightly fun ;)
if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
    raise SystemExit

# Draw the scene
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
for wall in walls:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
screen.blit(vstav.surf, vstav.rect)
screen.blit(vstae.surf, vstae.rect)
screen.blit(vstat.surf, vstat.rect)
screen.blit(vstao.surf, vstao.rect)
screen.blit(vstaf.surf, vstaf.rect)

pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `screen.fill` должен вызываться каждый кадр перед обновлением экрана.
Измените конец главного цикла while:

```
while not done:
    ...
    screen.fill(RED)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60) # количество кадров
```